# Splitting a String and then displaying a portion of that split (last name part)

Tags: java

Hey I'm having an issue with the following problem. I understand how to split the formalName variable (a first " " last name) but now I'm having trouble just displaying the last name so I can generate the formalName ("Mr./Ms. " lastName) can anyone help?

> Complete the generateFormalName method so that… you return the formal
>   name (Mr. or Ms. + last name) given a full name and gender (Strings)
>   as parameters.
>
> --You can assume a valid name & gender (any case allowed) is passed in. Example 1: ("Bob Smith", "MaLE") passed in should generate "Mr.
>   Smith" Example 2: ("Maggie May", "feMALE") passed in should generate
>   "Ms. May"
>
> Tip 1: You are given a String formalName initialized to the empty
>   String -- you will want to concatenate other Strings onto this to
>   produce the full formalName.
>
> Tip 2: Write your algorithm in English first.
>
> Tip 3: Think of all of the methods at your disposal and which could be
>   helpful.

Comment: which trouble? what about adding the code you already have, it will make it easier to get an understanding of your issues.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Also check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask. Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). Also see 
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Properly format your question (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and include the code.

Answer (score 2):

split() function returns you an array of strings. You need to get second element from the array. You can try something like this:

```
String fullName = "John Smith";
String lastName = fullName.split(" ")[1];
String formalName = "Mr./Ms. " + lastName;
```

Comment: He still needs to add one more if in the method to check gender:)

Comment: I'd have proposed `"John Smith".replaceAll("^\\w", "Mr./Ms.")`